# Put ImageView on top of 3d object Android

Tags: android, android-layout, 3d, imageview

I'm looking for a library or something else that will allow me to use some image view as "background" to another image view.
The idea is that the background will be let's say a cup of coffee and i want to replace the front side of the cup with custom Image View.
I'm not talking put one image on top of another via **FrameLayout**, but something else.

How can this be achieved?

Example Image:
[image]

Comment: You can also achieve it using overlapping two image view inside Constraint Layout

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xml, not jatpack compose, maybe you can use background attribute as background and src attribute for actual image.

Comment: The idea is that the changeable imageview should curve depends the coffee cup structure. Probably some code should be applied to the imageview and then only dynamically changing the Image Src.